# How to overwrite a file?

Tags: python, csv, truncate, writefile

This question is directly linked to my *"How to modify a tsv-file column with Python"* question. Briefly: I'd like to overwrite the first column of a TSV file, by changing a certain symbol (`in_char`) with another one (`out_char`).
In order to write over the original file, I thought to use the `.truncate()` method by writing this:

```
with open(my_file, "r+") as mf:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in mf]
    for line in lines:
        line = line.replace(in_char, out_char, 1)
        mf.seek(0)
        mf.write(line)
        mf.truncate()
mf.close()
```

Actually the file is correctly overwritten but only with the last row of the TSV, so I basically obtain a TSV with one row.

For example if my `in_char` is the "|" symbol and my `out_char` is the "_" symbol, from my original TSV:

```
A|circ  properties  m4  298 298 28  +   .   coverage=81;
B|circ  properties  m4  307 307 40  -   .   coverage=74;
C|circ  properties  m4  361 361 23  +   .   coverage=77;
```

This is what I obtain:

```
C_circ  properties  m4  361 361 23  +   .   coverage=77;
```

Where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: the write to file is outside the for loop, so it only saves the last line

Comment: @heretolearn actually it is but the problem remains :( The question has been updated with the ```.write(line)```inside the loop.

Comment: Don't read and write to the same file. Either read all the data in at once, make the changes, then write it all back out or create a temporary file to write to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are modifying the file as you read it. I suggest you take one of two approaches:

1. Read the entire file into memory, make the modifications, then write the file back out.
2. Create a temporary file to write to. Read the input file one line at a time, make the changes and write each line to the temporary file. Then rename the temporary file back to the original.

As an aside, I suggest using the standard `csv` module for this. In particular, `DictReader` and `DictWriter` make this task straightforward.

Comment: I'm a little shaky about that but I'll try. Thank you!

Comment: @Barbanera The key is to break a problem down into smaller pieces that either you know how to implement in Python or you can easily look up. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You could use pandas to load the file and update the values:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(input_file, sep='\t', header=None)
df[0] = df[0].str.replace('|','_')
```

To save the file back:

```
df.to_csv(output_file, sep='\t')
```

Assuming there is no header, if you have a column header use that in place of `0` in the subscript like `df['col1']`

Comment: And can pandas write the file back out again? (Not the OP, just asking)

Comment: yes, we can save back to the file as well. Updated my answer to show the save part.

Comment: @heretolearn thank you for the answer. I tried using your code but it gives back this error:
`pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 7, saw 9`

Comment: @Barbanera, the error seems to be in line no. 7 of the code as per the error message. If you could tell me what it is, may be i can try to fix that. The above code is based on the sample i put you provided and it seems to be working for me. Only the above 4 lines is required for the whole operation so not not sure what line no. 7 is.